# AWS Lambda with mapping of web socket routes to http endpoints in controllers and testing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm new to AWS Lambda, fascinating stuff. I am playing with some scenarios integrating AWS Lambda developed with `netcoreapp3.1` with AWS API Gateway.
I saw AWS Api Gateway supports web socket management, which is great because it deals with keeping connections open and sends any frame to the back-end lambda, and exposes some secured POST endpoint to send messages from back-end lambda to the client connected to the gateway's web socket. All the heavy lifting is there.

I also saw that there is some package for C# developers that allows using lambda applications as if they were a standard web api. See [https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-aws-lambda-supports-for-net-core-3-1](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-aws-lambda-supports-for-net-core-3-1/)
This is fantastic because I honestly don't get why some developers always try to have one lambda per endpoint, when a lambda can be used to route internally to whichever endpoint, and use all the goodness of the generic hosting for aspnet core 3.1+ plus logging, dependency injection container out of the box, etc. and a very nice way to test everything as if it was a web api application without worrying about the lambda entry point. See the package https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/tree/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer

The lambda entry point looks like this. As you can see, I just inherit from the package's `APIGatewayProxyFunction` class and everything uses the same as if I ran it locally as a kestrel web app.

```
public class LambdaEntryPoint
    : APIGatewayProxyFunction
{
    protected override void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

The `Program.cs` or local entry point when running it as a kestrel web app

```
public static class LocalEntryPoint
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        return Host
            .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(
                webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); });
    }
}
```

The `Startup.cs` looks like any standard Startup, with registrations and http pipeline, and knows nothing about whether it's being executed as a lambda or as a standard web app (great, isn't it? If only I could use this in a nice way for web sockets and test it...)

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
    }
}
```

Having said that, **I haven't been lucky to find any example on how to use an AWS Lambda with AspNetCore for web socket connectivity**.

Ideally I'd like my lambda application to be a web api with local and lambda entrypoint as described in that package (it has some nice samples) or by using the dotnet template called `serverless.AspNetCoreWebAPI`, but where I could also use it to map web socket routes, so that the same lambda application works with API Gateway REST and API Gateway Websocket

I have seen some workarounds like this https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/issues/644#issuecomment-621528565 where the methods `MarshallRequest` and `PostMarshallRequestFeature` are overriden, but I don't fully understand some things such as some class types and that brings me to the following questions:

- Can I have a lambda to serve both integration with REST and WebSocket Api Gateway? Is there any potential issue/recommendation to avoid it?
- How does API Gateway invoke the lambda function and how could I test this functionality? I've had a look at the https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/tree/master/Tools/LambdaTestTool and configured it to debug it with rider, but I am absolutely lost when having to test some websocket input. How to do that?

Ta.

---

**UPDATE 1** 2021-02-23:

Thanks. As per the event payload samples here they are:

- When `$connect` with `wscat -c wss://{api_id}.execute-api.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/Prod` the APIGatewayProxyRequest is:

  ```
  {
      "Resource": null,
      "Path": null,
      "HttpMethod": null,
      "Headers": {
          "Host": "xxx.execute-api.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com",
          "Sec-WebSocket-Extensions": "permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits",
          "Sec-WebSocket-Key": "xxx==",
          "Sec-WebSocket-Version": "13",
          "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6034bfdc-53e605153673d3cb0d0c4177",
          "X-Forwarded-For": "185.153.165.122",
          "X-Forwarded-Port": "443",
          "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https"
      },
      "MultiValueHeaders": {
          "Host": [
              "xxx.execute-api.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com"
          ],
          "Sec-WebSocket-Extensions": [
              "permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits"
          ],
          "Sec-WebSocket-Key": [
              "xxx=="
          ],
          "Sec-WebSocket-Version": [
              "13"
          ],
          "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": [
              "Root=1-6034bfdc-53e605153673ddcb0d0cxxx"
          ],
          "X-Forwarded-For": [
              "185.153.165.122"
          ],
          "X-Forwarded-Port": [
              "443"
          ],
          "X-Forwarded-Proto": [
              "https"
          ]
      },
      "QueryStringParameters": null,
      "MultiValueQueryStringParameters": null,
      "PathParameters": null,
      "StageVariables": null,
      "RequestContext": {
          "Path": null,
          "AccountId": null,
          "ResourceId": null,
          "Stage": "Prod",
          "RequestId": "xxx=",
          "Identity": {
              "CognitoIdentityPoolId": null,
              "AccountId": null,
              "CognitoIdentityId": null,
              "Caller": null,
              "ApiKey": null,
              "ApiKeyId": null,
              "AccessKey": null,
              "SourceIp": "185.153.165.122",
              "CognitoAuthenticationType": null,
              "CognitoAuthenticationProvider": null,
              "UserArn": null,
              "UserAgent": null,
              "User": null,
              "ClientCert": null
          },
          "ResourcePath": null,
          "HttpMethod": null,
          "ApiId": "xxx",
          "ExtendedRequestId": "xxx=",
          "ConnectionId": "xxx=",
          "ConnectionAt": 0,
          "DomainName": "xxx.execute-api.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com",
          "DomainPrefix": null,
          "EventType": "CONNECT",
          "MessageId": null,
          "RouteKey": "$connect",
          "Authorizer": null,
          "OperationName": null,
          "Error": null,
          "IntegrationLatency": null,
          "MessageDirection": "IN",
          "RequestTime": "23/Feb/2021:08:42:04 +0000",
          "RequestTimeEpoch": 1614069724309,
          "Status": null
      },
      "Body": null,
      "IsBase64Encoded": false
  }
  ```

  and the APIGatewayProxyResponse is:

  ```
  {
      "statusCode": 200,
      "headers": null,
      "multiValueHeaders": null,
      "body": "Connected.",
      "isBase64Encoded": false
  }
  ```
- When `sendmessage` `{"message":"sendmessage", "data":"hello world"}` the APIGatweayProxyRequest is:

  ```
  {
      "Resource": null,
      "Path": null,
      "HttpMethod": null,
      "Headers": null,
      "MultiValueHeaders": null,
      "QueryStringParameters": null,
      "MultiValueQueryStringParameters": null,
      "PathParameters": null,
      "StageVariables": null,
      "RequestContext": {
          "Path": null,
          "AccountId": null,
          "ResourceId": null,
          "Stage": "Prod",
          "RequestId": "xxx=",
          "Identity": {
              "CognitoIdentityPoolId": null,
              "AccountId": null,
              "CognitoIdentityId": null,
              "Caller": null,
              "ApiKey": null,
              "ApiKeyId": null,
              "AccessKey": null,
              "SourceIp": "185.153.165.122",
              "CognitoAuthenticationType": null,
              "CognitoAuthenticationProvider": null,
              "UserArn": null,
              "UserAgent": null,
              "User": null,
              "ClientCert": null
          },
          "ResourcePath": null,
          "HttpMethod": null,
          "ApiId": "xxx",
          "ExtendedRequestId": "xxx=",
          "ConnectionId": "xxx=",
          "ConnectionAt": 0,
          "DomainName": "4air0zk9w1.execute-api.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com",
          "DomainPrefix": null,
          "EventType": "MESSAGE",
          "MessageId": "xxx=",
          "RouteKey": "sendmessage",
          "Authorizer": null,
          "OperationName": null,
          "Error": null,
          "IntegrationLatency": null,
          "MessageDirection": "IN",
          "RequestTime": "23/Feb/2021:08:42:33 +0000",
          "RequestTimeEpoch": 1614069753002,
          "Status": null
      },
      "Body": "{\"message\":\"sendmessage\", \"data\":\"hello world\"}",
      "IsBase64Encoded": false
  }
  ```

  and the APIGatewayProxyResponse is:

  ```
  {
      "statusCode": 200,
      "headers": null,
      "multiValueHeaders": null,
      "body": "Data sent to 1 connection",
      "isBase64Encoded": false
  }
  ```
- When `$disconnect` the APIGatewayRequest is:

  ```
  {
      "Resource": null,
      "Path": null,
      "HttpMethod": null,
      "Headers": {
          "Host": "xxx.execute-api.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com",
          "x-api-key": "",
          "X-Forwarded-For": "",
          "x-restapi": ""
      },
      "MultiValueHeaders": {
          "Host": [
              "xxx.execute-api.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com"
          ],
          "x-api-key": [
              ""
          ],
          "X-Forwarded-For": [
              ""
          ],
          "x-restapi": [
              ""
          ]
      },
      "QueryStringParameters": null,
      "MultiValueQueryStringParameters": null,
      "PathParameters": null,
      "StageVariables": null,
      "RequestContext": {
          "Path": null,
          "AccountId": null,
          "ResourceId": null,
          "Stage": "Prod",
          "RequestId": "xxx=",
          "Identity": {
              "CognitoIdentityPoolId": null,
              "AccountId": null,
              "CognitoIdentityId": null,
              "Caller": null,
              "ApiKey": null,
              "ApiKeyId": null,
              "AccessKey": null,
              "SourceIp": "185.153.165.122",
              "CognitoAuthenticationType": null,
              "CognitoAuthenticationProvider": null,
              "UserArn": null,
              "UserAgent": null,
              "User": null,
              "ClientCert": null
          },
          "ResourcePath": null,
          "HttpMethod": null,
          "ApiId": "xxx",
          "ExtendedRequestId": "xxxA=",
          "ConnectionId": "xxx=",
          "ConnectionAt": 0,
          "DomainName": "xxx.execute-api.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com",
          "DomainPrefix": null,
          "EventType": "DISCONNECT",
          "MessageId": null,
          "RouteKey": "$disconnect",
          "Authorizer": null,
          "OperationName": null,
          "Error": null,
          "IntegrationLatency": null,
          "MessageDirection": "IN",
          "RequestTime": "23/Feb/2021:08:42:41 +0000",
          "RequestTimeEpoch": 1614069761070,
          "Status": null
      },
      "Body": null,
      "IsBase64Encoded": false
  }
  ```

  and the APIGatewayProxyResponse is:

  ```
  {
      "statusCode": 200,
      "headers": null,
      "multiValueHeaders": null,
      "body": "Disconnected.",
      "isBase64Encoded": false
  }
  ```

Comment: Hey. That's a good and interesting question. Unfortunately, I don't know the answer and as you've mentioned, my company maps individual lambdas directly to endpoints. Although, I am curious, what happens if you add the SignalR package and map your hubs along with endpoints as we do it on standard asp.net core app? Like so: 
`endpoints.MapControllers(); 
 endpoints.MapHub<YourHub>("/signalr/yourHub");` ?

Comment: From what I've read here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9522 is not something easy or even possible. At the end the api gateway is dealing with connections and the lambda "just" needs to react to the connect, disconnect and other events